# Get record id using GridView Linkbutton on one page and get on another page in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, linkbutton

How do I submit  the `id` from one page to another page in `ASP.NET` using `C#`? I have a GridView control and each record contains a link button:

```
<asp:TemplateField>              
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_naatscat" runat="server" Text="arshad" CommandName="view_user_naats_gv" Font-Underline="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I've bound the `id` to link button:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbtn_naatscat")).CommandArgument 
        = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "cate_id").ToString();
    ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbtn_naatscat")).Text 
        = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "title").ToString();
}
```

now I want to pass this `id` to another page when user click to this link button.

Comment: you could pass the values in the query string of the request

Comment: Depends on if you wanna use post or get.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the `LinkButton's` [`Command` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.command.aspx) and use the `CommandArgument`:

```
void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    if(e.CommandName == "view_user_naats_gv")
    {
        Resonse.Redirect("UserNaats.aspx?catID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Session` for this purpose.

Do as follows:

```
Session["Id"]=e.CommandArgument.ToString() //Id you want to pass to next page
```

In this way your Session variable will get created. And you will be able to access it on the next page.

While retrieving it on next page:

```
Id=Session["Id"]
```

**Other Alternatives:**

1. View state
2. Control state
3. Hidden fields
4. Cookies
5. Query strings
6. Application state
7. Session state
8. Profile Properties

**State management Techniques in ASP.NET:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a hidden field, and access it on the next page in the code behind file.

[Here is another SO post with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600109/how-to-get-hiddenfield-value-in-asp-net-code-behind)

[Another example of passing hidden field in ASP](http://forums.devshed.com/asp-programming-51/passing-asp-via-hidden-form-fields-51717.html)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx)  field like so

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Database ID Field" 
                           DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/PageName.aspx?ID={0}" 
                           DataTextField="Database ID Field" HeaderText="ID" />
```

And then on the page that you're redirecting to, you would check the query string for ID

```
   string id = Request.QueryString["ID"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `PostBackUrl` and `CommandArgument` properties of the `LinkButton` in your source page like so:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>              
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_naatscat" runat="server" Text="arshad" CommandName="view_user_naats_gv" Font-Underline="false" PostBackUrl="~/YourPage.aspx" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("submitid")%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then on your page that is being submitted to you can place the following directive to the `DestinationPage.aspx` page:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>
```

I don't know what type of container the `<ItemTemplate>` tag is from (`ListView`?). However you can find the control in the `DestinationPage.aspx` page like so:

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null && Page.PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostback) {
  // if you use the PreviousPageDirective you should be able to access the ListView
  // property directly
  // var listView = Page.PreviousPage.MyListView;
  var listView = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("MyListView") as ListView;
  var linkButton = listView.FindControl("lbtn_naatscat") as LinkButton;
  var submitId = linkButton.CommandArgument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Row_Command` event you can send it next page using query string.

```
protected void gvDeals_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.CommandName.Equals("MyCommand")
   {
      string value=calculate();
      Response.Redirect("~/MyPage.aspx?item=" + value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to use a hyperlink in your GridView.
For example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="link_naatscat" runat="Server"                                             
        Text="arshad"
        ToolTip="arshad"
        NavigateUrl=<%#"~/YourPage.aspx?id=" + Eval("submitid")%>>
    </asp:HyperLink> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the id this way

```
 Response.Redirect("/yourpage.aspx?" + id);
```

And get it this way

```
 String s = "";
            foreach (String item in Request.QueryString.Keys)
            {
                s = Request.QueryString[item];
            }
            if (s != "")
            {
                id = Int32.Parse(s);
            }
```

Comment: Why loop over the collection for a single item? You can access the item directly with a proper null wrapper.