# How to get the value of hidden field in the server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net page and I have set the hidden field value through the javascript. Now I need to fetch the value of hidden field in the server side, but it returns the blank. Can anyone tell me how to get  the value of hidden field in the server side.

Set the value of hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnMy" name="hdnMy" class="hdnMy" runat="Server"  />
```

in the javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hdnMy").val("Pankaj");
});
```

Now need to fetch the value of Page_load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = hdnMy.value;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600109/how-to-get-hiddenfield-value-in-asp-net-code-behind

Answer (score 2):

You can get its value by using its Value property.

```
this.hdnMy.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

1. $(".hdnMy") is a class Selector returns an array of dom objects. So either you should use :

   ```
   $("#hdnMy").val("Pankaj")
   ```

or

```
$(".hdnMy").each(function(){
   $(this).val("Pankaj");
});
```

In server side you should be able to get it by name of the field.

```
string hdnName= Request.Form["hdnName"].ToString();
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways

```
1) var Hiddenvalue= document.getElementById('<%= idofhiddenfield.ClientID%>');
```

2)
Assign value to your Hidden field like below

```
$("#<%=idofhiddenfield.ClientID%>").val("value");
```

Then code behind you can call it like

```
string value=idofhiddenfield.value;
```

3)Or you can pass it as a querystring then take it in code behind

4) or add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to hiddenfield 
then do something like you had done in your code 
like

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnMy" name="hdnMy" class="hdnMy" runat="Server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

then the below code will work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hdnMy").val("Pankaj");
});
```

Comment: Actually i need to fetch the value in the Page_load event of the page. But it returns the blank, however it has been set the value to that hidden field.

Comment: Sorry server side code executes first then client side code. I think you are try to set hidden field value in client side then try to get it in page load . how can we get it ? because server side is first loaded .

Comment: When you try to get it in page load hidden field value always empty if you are assigning the values from client side

Comment: try to get it in a buttonclick event definitely it will get

Answer (score 0):

*Once the form is submitted to the server there is no difference between hidden fields and normal fields.*

comment: *use the `id` instead of `class` if you want to set the value of one input field.*

To fetch the value:

```
var val = $("#hdnMy").val()
```

Comment: I have set the value in the ready method. But it is not working $(document).ready(function () {


    $(".hdnMy").val("pankaj");


});

Comment: really? use console.log or alert to make sure your code is actually executing.

Comment: @user1053922 use  this $(document).ready(function() {
    $("<%= hdnMy.ClientID %>").val("your value");
});